# java final keyword causes error: unreachable statement. why is it not printing hello world

Tags: java, final

```
error: unreachable statement
```

why is it not printing hello world?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int a=10,b=20;
        while(a>b){
            System.out.print("Message");
        }
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: How can `a>b` ever be true and enter the loop? Also the problem is not that this doesn't print "Hello world". This doesn't even compile to begin with.

Comment: Then you get stuck in the loop and the last statement becomes unreachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a>b` in your code is a so-called constant expression because `a` and `b` are `final` and assigned with a literal value (same would apply if it would have been assigned with another constant expression). The Java compiler evaluates these constant expressions during compilation. Because it evaluates to `false`, it decides that the `while` loop will never be executed, and thus the content of the loop is an "unreachable statement", and compilation fails with an error.

It never prints "Hello World", because compilation fails, so the code is never run. Printing happens at run time, not compile time.

Comment: what if a=30 and b=20 then ..

Comment: @VIJAYKUMAR Then the compiler will evaluate that the expression is true, and that the while-loop is an infinite loop as there is no break inside the loop, and so it decides that the code *after* the loop is unreachable, and so compilation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Because you make `a` and `b` final, the java compiler sees that:

```java
while(a > b)
```

will never be true. Because it knows before running the program, it won't let you keep that code. Aka you have remove the while, or remove the words `final` before the variables `a` and `b`.